# phabricator - how to get attachment using API

Tags: phabricator

How to get attachment of a phabricator ticket using api. If I pull the data using maniphest.gettasktransactions, I get a key for attachement like {abcd}. Can someone please guide how to get attachment using this key.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Attachments" or "{abcd}" in Phabricator. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, Chad. Actually by attachment I mean any image/file etc. Let say I have dragged an image along with some text in description. I want to get it using code. When I pull this data using API, I got the text but for image, I got like {abcd23} and I am assuming this is a key to download that image using any other API. I am not sure hence please suggest how we can pull image/file from a ticket. Overall purpose of this exercise is to export a ticket info to a csv using Python.

Comment: We use monograms for objects, so for a file it would be {F123} for File ID #123. file.info can give you the PHID, and file.download will let you download.

Comment: CSV can be exported directly from Maniphest under "Export to Excel", though I don't know if it also returns files.

Comment: Thanks Chad for the pointer. I tried to call file.info to get file PHID without much success like func('file.info',{'phid': "{F8895}" }), its returning "None", and I am not sure if I calling it in a right way. "func" is a custom method which further hits provided API with parameters. I am wondering if you could please provide a sample code to get File info and download file?

Comment: F12345 is a Monogram. "F" is the Monogram. "12345" is the ID. Neither of these are PHIDs.



echo '{
  "id": 1710373
}' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri https://secure.phabricator.com/ --conduit-token <conduit-token> file.info